# Variable not initialising java

Tags: java, variables, matrix, initialization

On line 38 -

```
pool.submit(new Multi(N,i,j,a,b,c));
```

I have a variable `j` which is not initializing. I'm not sure what's wrong as all others have initialized, this has been bugging me for the past hour.

Please could someone help me fix this error?

```
public class Matrix1 
{       
    public final static int N = 4; //Random size of matrix

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {           
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Create and multiply matrix of random size N.   
        double [][] a = new double [N][N];
        double [][] b = new double [N][N];
        double [][] c = new double [N][N];          
        int i,j,k;

        for(i = 0; i < N ; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < N ; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = i + j;
                b[i][j] = i * j;
            }

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                c[i][j] = 0;

                for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
                   c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; //C matrix calculated from a and B matrices.               
            }  

        pool.submit(new Multi(N,i,j,a,b,c));
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Calculation completed in " +
        (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");       
    }

    static class Multi implements Runnable 
    {
        final int N;
        final double [][] a;
        final double [][] b;
        final double [][] c;
        final int i;
        final int j;

        public Multi(int N, int i, int j, double[][] a, double[][] b, double[][] c)
        {
            this.N=N;
            this.i=i;
            this.j=j;
            this.a=a;
            this.b=b;
            this.c=c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < N; k++) 
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 38? Are you really expecting us to count the lines in your code-dump?

Comment: Counting the line isnt hard, but ive editted my post. Sory about that

Comment: The problem is that it is harder in the Stack Overflow UI since formatting may cause leading or trailing lines to be lost, and the IDE you might be using should provide line numbers.

Comment: Well yeah. If N is 0 then nothing ever gets assigned to `j`. The compiler is right in this case. (Note that adding a `if(N > 0)` check will not fix the error, because the compiler isn't smart enough to know that fixes the problem)

Comment: So how do i sort this out :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to access the dummy variable `j` outside of its loop.  Try the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) { 
        c[i][j] = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; // C matrix calculated from a and B matrices.
        }

        pool.submit(new Multi(N,i,j,a,b,c));
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers worked great! Cant believe i missed that {